# Tableau + Redshift slowness in cursors

Tags: amazon-redshift, tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I know that Tableau Server uses cursors to refresh extracts, however, for running some simple queries that have large amounts of columns there is a large inconsistency in duration of the execution of some of this cursors. For example, when I run:

```
select * from svl_qlog
where userid = (select usesysid from pg_user where usename='tableau')
order by starttime desc
limit 20;
```

I get:

```
+------+--------+--------+----+--------------------------+--------------------------+---------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+------------+------------------------------+------------+
|userid|query   |xid     |pid |starttime                 |endtime                   |elapsed  |aborted|label                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |substring                                                   |source_query|concurrency_scaling_status_txt|from_sp_call|
+------+--------+--------+----+--------------------------+--------------------------+---------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+------------+------------------------------+------------+
|108   |14993377|36192048|3270|2021-08-24 03:34:48.862153|2021-08-24 03:38:09.404563|200542410|0      |default                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |fetch 100000 in "SQL_CUR7";                                 |NULL        |0 - Ran on the main cluster   |NULL        |
|108   |14993370|36192035|3270|2021-08-24 03:34:41.174557|2021-08-24 03:34:41.185152|10595    |0      |default                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |fetch 100000 in "SQL_CUR6";                                 |NULL        |0 - Ran on the main cluster   |NULL        |
|108   |14993368|36192034|3270|2021-08-24 03:34:40.991779|2021-08-24 03:34:41.021350|29571    |0      |default                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |Undoing 1 transactions on table 1728726 with current xid 361|NULL        |0 - Ran on the main cluster   |NULL        |
|108   |14993367|36192032|3270|2021-08-24 03:34:40.861741|2021-08-24 03:34:40.907681|45940    |0      |default                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |fetch 100000 in "SQL_CUR3";                                 |NULL        |0 - Ran on the main cluster   |NULL        |
|108   |14993365|36192025|3262|2021-08-24 03:34:38.135543|2021-08-24 03:34:38.229458|93915    |0      |default                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |fetch 100000 in "SQL_CUR7";                                 |NULL        |0 - Ran on the main cluster   |NULL        |
|108   |14993363|36192022|3262|2021-08-24 03:34:38.006010|2021-08-24 03:34:38.008911|2901     |0      |default                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |fetch 100000 in "SQL_CUR6";                                 |NULL        |0 - Ran on the main cluster   |NULL        |
|108   |14993360|36192020|3262|2021-08-24 03:34:37.250081|2021-08-24 03:34:37.885200|635119   |0      |default                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |Undoing 1 transactions on table 1728724 with current xid 361|NULL        |0 - Ran on the main cluster   |NULL        |
|108   |14993359|36192018|3262|2021-08-24 03:34:35.811267|2021-08-24 03:34:35.865765|54498    |0      |default                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |fetch 100000 in "SQL_CUR3";                                 |NULL        |0 - Ran on the main cluster   |NULL        |
|108   |14993287|36191920|2934|2021-08-24 03:33:16.921494|2021-08-24 03:33:38.143570|21222076 |0      |default                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |fetch 100000 in "SQL_CUR7";                                 |NULL        |0 - Ran on the main cluster   |NULL        |
|108   |14993285|36191917|2934|2021-08-24 03:33:16.618563|2021-08-24 03:33:16.623745|5182     |0      |default                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |fetch 100000 in "SQL_CUR6";                                 |NULL        |0 - Ran on the main cluster   |NULL        |
|108   |14993281|36191916|2934|2021-08-24 03:33:15.619813|2021-08-24 03:33:16.493711|873898   |0      |default                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |Undoing 1 transactions on table 1728722 with current xid 361|NULL        |0 - Ran on the main cluster   |NULL        |
|108   |14993280|36191914|2934|2021-08-24 03:33:14.720016|2021-08-24 03:33:14.787236|67220    |0      |default                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |fetch 100000 in "SQL_CUR3";                                 |NULL        |0 - Ran on the main cluster   |NULL        |
|108   |14993071|36191663|2258|2021-08-24 03:30:25.760462|2021-08-24 03:31:05.340131|39579669 |0      |default                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |fetch 100000 in "SQL_CUR7";                                 |NULL        |0 - Ran on the main cluster   |NULL        |
|108   |14993069|36191660|2258|2021-08-24 03:30:25.359800|2021-08-24 03:30:25.366651|6851     |0      |default                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |fetch 100000 in "SQL_CUR6";                                 |NULL        |0 - Ran on the main cluster   |NULL        |
|108   |14993064|36191657|2258|2021-08-24 03:30:25.170646|2021-08-24 03:30:25.245196|74550    |0      |default                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |Undoing 1 transactions on table 1728720 with current xid 361|NULL        |0 - Ran on the main cluster   |NULL        |
|108   |14993063|36191655|2258|2021-08-24 03:30:25.045651|2021-08-24 03:30:25.079935|34284    |0      |default                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |fetch 100000 in "SQL_CUR3";                                 |NULL        |0 - Ran on the main cluster   |NULL        |
|108   |14993053|36191642|2182|2021-08-24 03:30:18.163032|2021-08-24 03:30:18.381360|218328   |0      |default                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |fetch 100000 in "SQL_CUR7";                                 |NULL        |0 - Ran on the main cluster   |NULL        |
|108   |14993050|36191638|2182|2021-08-24 03:30:18.029206|2021-08-24 03:30:18.032746|3540     |0      |default                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |fetch 100000 in "SQL_CUR6";                                 |NULL        |0 - Ran on the main cluster   |NULL        |
|108   |14993043|36191620|2182|2021-08-24 03:30:15.207471|2021-08-24 03:30:15.853592|646121   |0      |default                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |Undoing 1 transactions on table 1728718 with current xid 361|NULL        |0 - Ran on the main cluster   |NULL        |
|108   |14993042|36191618|2182|2021-08-24 03:30:14.086680|2021-08-24 03:30:14.131522|44842    |0      |default                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |fetch 100000 in "SQL_CUR3";                                 |NULL        |0 - Ran on the main cluster   |NULL        |
+------+--------+--------+----+--------------------------+--------------------------+---------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+------------+------------------------------+------------+
```

Just by eyeballing the elapsed column, you can tell the problem. So, my question is, is there a known reason for some of these cursors to take way longer? Also, is Tableau or Redshift the culprit here? And what's with these:

```
Undoing 1 transactions on table 1728722 with current xid 361
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The first fetch to the cursor runs the query.  Subsequent fetches just retrieves the next set of data that is already computed and waiting on the leader node. In your example it looks like your returned data is less than 10K rows as I don't see subsequent fetches for the same transaction.  Is this correct or are you missing some fetches?  Since you say that you are refreshing extracts it seems like more data would be expected but I don't know your situation.

Given this it is likely that the different fetch times are due to differing query complexities and run times.  If you look at activity (svl_statementtext) for these XIDs you can see what query is being sent to populate the cursor.  You can then run these queries yourself and see how complex they are and general run times.

Other possibilities include queuing delays and/or high query load of the database and/or high load on the leader node.

Do you know the size of the dataset being returned?  If this is very very large then there is likely better ways to get the refresh data to Tableau.  Pulling data through the leader node with a select query but these methods take effort to set up.

Questions to answer - What queries go with which fetches?  How long do these take to run standalone?  How much data does each query return?  Knowing these answers will help is setting a path for improvement.

Comment: To answer your questions, all the queries (6 of them) are in the form of: `select [col1, col2, ....] from table where date >= current_date - 365` and the 3 biggest ones have 30+ columns and about 4MM rows each. All those datasets are already aggregated and have been trimmed down as much as possible.  This happens while the DB (6 ds2 8xlarge nodes) is sitting in idle. The datasets are extracted in their entirety, however, with 100k fetches, `svl_qlog` does not seem to have the statements for all the trips needed for the extraction. Tableau Server is m5 4xlarge.

Comment: So if you run the query that take 200 sec manually (into a temp table) how long does it take to run?

Comment: You can see the run time of the other fetches in svl_statementtext.  They SHOULD be very short

Comment: The data transfer time shouldn't be too long at these sizes - assuming that there isn't some bottleneck in between.  Are the Redshift cluster and the Tableau server in the same VPC?

Comment: We have similar problems with Tableau and Redshift. I will add the following; first, custom sql data connections are the slowest performing. Tableau makes the query into a view and then computes all your calculated fields off of that view. Second, Views in general are slower than physical tables, at least in my experience.